# Hot to get all parameter of URL and then add a parameter to that in wso2ESB

Tags: web-services, wso2-esb

I am working on wso2ESB version 4.9. I have URL in proxy and i want get all parameter when call proxy and then add a parameter to that.

For example:

```
www.example.com/call/sample?id=1&name=alice.
```

and then add a family parameter to above link

Note: I do not know about a parameter of URL.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer in this link

http://nuwanwimalasekara.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-append-query-parameter-to-api.html

I used this:

```
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="fn:concat(get property('axis2','REST_URL_POSTFIX'), '&amp;exchange=xyz')"/>
```

Thanks @Bhathiya.